# Qiskit CNOT-gate matrix mixup?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, entanglement, pauli-gates

In the qiskit textbook [chapter 1.3.1](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/multiple-qubits-entangled-states.html#3.1-The-CNOT-Gate-) "The CNOT-Gate" it says that the matrix representation on the right is the own corresponding to the circuit shown above, with q_0 being the control and q_1 the target, but shouldn't this matrix representation be for the case of q_1 being the control and q_0 the target? This seems to be presented the other way round...or there seems to be something I am not quite getting yet.

Thanks so much :)

Quick edit: By "right" I am referring to this:
[image]

Comment: Alright, I was guessing you meant something else. In this terms @Egretta.Thula is the correct one. Cheers! :)

Comment: I went to the textbook and it says that the **left** matrix corresponds to the circuit above: "In our case, the left matrix corresponds to the CNOT in the circuit above".

Comment: Related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15287/9858

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Qiskit uses "**little endian**" bit ordering. That means, if A and B are $2 \times 2$ unitary matrices then
$B \otimes A$ (note the order) is equivalent to applying $A$ to first qubit and $B$ to second qubit.

Hence,
$$CNOT = I \otimes P_0 + X \otimes P_1$$
where
$$
P_0 = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} 1&0 \\ 0&0 \end{array}} \right)
, P_1 = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} 0&0 \\ 0&1 \end{array}} \right)
$$

If you do the matrix multiplication, you should get
$$CNOT = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \end{array}} \right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I was missing :)

Comment: But the examples are not presented like this in text, right? Is there a footnote or anything that introduces this convention? It does make sense but it seems a bit inconsistent since the tensor product is not introduced nor treated with this convention...

Comment: Actually, it is in the same web page. Just (re)read section 2 in the same chapter (Single Qubit Gates on Multi-Qubit Statevectors). Notice the circuit where $H$ is applied to $q_0$ and $X$ is applied to $q_1$ and see how its unitary is calculated.

Comment: See here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.CXGate.html#qiskit.circuit.library.CXGate

Comment: @Egretta.Thula I am so sorry. I just copied it the other way round while doing the math, anticipating the change of order and basically changing it twice. Thanks so much for your patience!!! :)))

Comment: @KAJ226 Thank you! :)

Answer (score -4):

[image]

Hi there. the Matrix for `0,1` is to represent `Q[0] = 1` to be effective, right, so that I wrote & got the answer for the Coefficient to be `|01>` is `1` in the last column of the Density Matrix.

Consequently do note that the for CNOT for `1,0` to be effecive `Q[1]` must be one so i get the representation of the the co-efficient of `|10>` to be 1 as the the last column of the matrix.

Also my Dears, Please do kindly note that the Density Matrix column has direct Relationship with the State Specially the 1st & last column.

Comment: The image that you linked isn't correctly displayed and please write your equations using Latex. Just enclose them in '\$' for inline equations and '\$\$' for equations centered in their own line.