# ctrl_state 'order' of control( )

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate

I am qurious about the order of ctrl_state

The Quantum Circuit what I expected is this.

[image]

q1 is controled when '0' and q2 and a3 is controled when '1'

So I wirte code that is

> ctrl_state='011'

But what I got is this. Why I got oposite form like this...
What is the principle of this.

[image]

```
from qiskit import*
from qiskit.extensions import UnitaryGate
matrix_V2_2=[[1,0],[0,1]]
Won_gate = UnitaryGate(matrix_V2_2,label='Won').control(num_ctrl_qubits=3, ctrl_state='011')
main_circuit=QuantumCircuit(4,4)
main_circuit.append(Won_gate ,[1,2,3,0])
%matplotlib inline
main_circuit.draw(output='mpl')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Qiskit uses [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) bit ordering. That means, in your case `ctrl_state` should be $q_3 q_2 q_1$.

You can find more details [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8244/9474) and [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18630/9474).

Comment: Thanks. I got it

Comment: You should "approve" the answer.