# How use UnitaryGate to creat a CNOT gate?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, unitarity

This is my code using qiskit below. I am not familiar with Unitarygate, so I tried to creat a cnot-gate.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.extensions import UnitaryGate
import numpy as np

matrix1 = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 1, 0]]
gatecx = UnitaryGate(matrix1)
matrix2 = [[0,1],
          [1,0]]
gatex = UnitaryGate(matrix2)
matrix3 = [[1/np.sqrt(2),1/np.sqrt(2)],
           [1/np.sqrt(2),-1/np.sqrt(2)]]
gateh = UnitaryGate(matrix3)

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
circuit.append(gatex,[0])
circuit.append(gatecx,[0,1])
circuit.draw('mpl',scale=0.6)
```

I apply a x-gate to qubit0 first, then apply a cx-gate.
[image]

After running this code, qubit1 haven't be flipped. The result have shown that qubit0 is target-q and qubit1 is control-q. That is beyond comprehension!!
[image]

What make me confused is why qubit0 isn't control-qubit in code `circuit.append(gatecx,[0,1])`?

Then I swapped the position of 0 and 1, `circuit.append(gatecx,[1,0])`, qubit1 was flipped. Is the first position a control qubit?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is because Qiskit uses *little endian* bit ordering. See the details [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18633/9474).

So, in your code should define `matrix1` as follows:

```
matrix1 = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0]
]
```

You may also use the fact that Qiskit saves matrix representation in the gate to define `matrix1`

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import CXGate

matrix1 = CXGate().to_matrix()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After reading the link above and the docs of qiskit, I found that to be the case. Although I think that's a little counter-intuitive...